Исключение The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process
C#, Windows Forms, SQLite
В форме есть метод ChangeProfileImage(), который по клику на PictureBox вызывает OpenFileDialog, позволяя выбрать фото профиля (аватар) на диске, после чего PictureBox отображает этот файл, сам файл сохраняется в папку %appdata%\LibraryApp\avatars, а имя файла записывается в БД (через вызов статического метода AccountActions.SetImagePathData()
private void ChangeProfileImage(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // opening the file dialog
    libraryManagerOpenFileDialog.FileName = "Image";
    libraryManagerOpenFileDialog.Filter = "PNG (*.png)|*.png";
    libraryManagerOpenFileDialog.Title = "Выберите файл с изображением";

    if (libraryManagerOpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
        return;

    // saving the image to the PictureBox
    libraryManagerPictureBox.BackgroundImage = null;

    libraryManagerPictureBox.Image = new Bitmap(libraryManagerOpenFileDialog.FileName);

    libraryManagerPictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
    libraryManagerPictureBox.Update();

    // the name of the file to save
    string fileName = account.Login + ".png";

    // the saving path
    string savePath = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%appdata%\LibraryApp\avatars\") + fileName;

    if (libraryManagerPictureBox.Image is not null)
    {
        try
        {
            // if a file with the same name already exists, delete it
            if (File.Exists(savePath))
                File.Delete(savePath);

            // saving the file
            libraryManagerPictureBox.Image.Save(savePath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            AccountActions.SetImagePathData(command, fileName, account.LoginId);
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Невозможно сохранить изображение профиля", "Ошибка",
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
}


public static void SetImagePathData(SqliteCommand command, string path, int LoginId)
{
    string query = "UPDATE Accounts SET ImagePath = @Path WHERE LoginId = @LoginId;";

    try
    {
        command = DataBase.GetConnection().CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = query;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Path", path);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoginId", LoginId);

        DataBase.OpenConnection();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"Не удалось создать запись в таблице Accounts. Ошибка:\n\"{ex.Message}\"\n" +
                        $"Обратитесь к системному администратору для её устранения.",
                        "Ошибка при работе с базой данных", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
    }

    DataBase.CloseConnection();
}


И всё работает, сохранение (и перезапись) файла происходит, в базу данных информация тоже пишется. Проблема в том, что после перезапуска программы при попытке перезаписать тот же файл аватарки файл занят другим процессом.
Если файл с базой данных заменить, то перезапись файла работает.
Подскажите, где может быть утечка памяти? И что сделать?

Вы файл при перезапуске используете?

Значит он загружен, открыт где-то в другом месте. В тексте исключения написано ровно то что происходит. Показали кусок рабочего кода и в конце написпли, что проблема не в нём. Логика вышла из чата :)

@tym32167 Нет. не использую. В этом и дело.

@aepot Где вы прочитали, что проблема не в коде? Я же написал, что при замене файла базы данных проблема с занятостью файла изображения пропадает. Может, есть проблема в закрытии соединения с БД в методе SetImagePathData(). Просто я её не увидел

Проблема в том что файл картинки на мрмпнт старта метода уже открыт в другом месте.

@aepot Да, и дело еще в вызове метода SetImagePathData(), который пишет в базу. Если закомментить его вызов, то файл с картинкой перезаписывается нормально. Просто, как связана занятость файла картинки и обращение к базе данных...

С тем что после перезапуска приложения вы читаете путь картинки из базы и загружаете её с диска на экран. Если в базе ничего нет, то ничего и не читаете.
